# Vue.js Non-blocking while statement (polling backend until progress is finished)

Tags: vue.js, async-await, vuejs2, vuex

Inside a vue action, I want to poll my backend (call another `async` action like described below? ) until the something has finished processing (frontend shows a loader until progress is over).

In other words, I want to repeatedly make an API call looking like :

```
actions: {
    load: async ({dispatch, commit, state}, {args}) => {
    await dispatch('progressPolling', {progressUrl, userId})
    // continue ONLY when progress has finished, else blocks at this statement
    ...
    }

    progressPolling: async ({dispatch, commit}, {progressUrl, userId}) => {
        var finished = false
        while(!finished) : {
            var progress = await dispatch('getResource', {url: progressUrl, userId: userId})
            finished = (progress.data.finished === true)
            // timeout of 2 secs
         }
    }
...
}
```

My understanding is that that you can use the `setTimeout()` statement to wait between calls, but am not sure how to turn this into a non-blocking while statement, or simply what is the best practice to achieve this.

**EDIT**: "Non-blocking" because I was originally using a `wait()` statement in a `while` loop. That made the UI freeze each time it had to wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use recursive function to do this.

```
progressPolling: async ({dispatch, commit}, {progressUrl, userId}) => {
    // Define a recursive function
    async function getResource (resolve) {
        const progress = await dispatch('getResource', {url: progressUrl, userId: userId})
        // Recurse when not finished
        if (progress.data.finished !== true) {
            setTimeout( () => getResource(resolve), 2000);
        } 
    }
    // Kick the recursive function
    return new Promise (resolve => getResource(resolve))
    // Finished!
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! Any chance you could add a `setTimeout()` in your example ? I want to wait 2 secs between calls to avoid overloading the API

Comment: Thank you ! I have the impression that the calling statement  (the first `await dispatch` in my example code)  seems to wait only for the first iteration, even though it's still polling. Any idea ?

Comment: I realize now that my question might confuse a bit. `non-blocking` because I was using a `wait()` statement and that made the UI freeze (since wait is blocking). I wanted to use an async behavior to avoid blocking the UI, but still blocking the calling statement untill the progress has finished.